# Why does Android restart apps?

Tags: android

Recently my Android TV app has started to restart itself about every an hour. The min SDK version is 27 and the tv is Sony Bravia.

So when the exoplayer (r2.15.0) in my app is playing HLS in full screen, the app might throw users back to the main screen of my app. The main screen is a few Activities away from the video screen.

I have tried adb but every time this happens, the Android studio only shows the adb disconnects. There hasn’t been any logs that I can look at.

But if I just let the app run videos in the emulator on my computer, it is fine.

Any people have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Usually due to memory issues (memory leaks eating up all the memory). Another would be a setting where you can set it so the OS closes background apps and reopens them when being active.